# Common ground circuit on Raspberry Pi blew fuse?

Tags: transistors, raspberry-pi

I tried experimenting with transistors for the first time and using my Raspberry Pi to try to control a higher voltage circuit. Using a breadboard, this is the circuit I tried to build (apologies for the poor hand-drawing):

[image: Circuit diagram]

My thought was that the 9V battery would operate the motor, and by having a common ground between it and the Pi, I would be able to use the Pi input to turn the transistor on or off.

About midway through, I realized that the pin voltage from the Pi wouldn't be high enough to flip the PNP transistor, but I went ahead anyway thinking that, in the worst case, the transistor would just be left continueously open. What I did not expect was that the circuit would fry my Pi entirely! (at least I was itching to upgrade it anyway :).

I'm pretty certain that I didn't inadvertantly short any pins or connect the 9V hot to the Pi's GND, so what went wrong in this circuit?

Comment: the base of the transistor has 8.4V on it. there is around .6V drop between the emitter and base. that is how you let out the `magic smoke` that makes all the electronic devices work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transistor E-B junction is forward biased from the +9V input, which puts 9V minus a diode drop on the Raspberry Pi input, which will indeed damage it. So it did exactly what we could have predicted it would do. If a fuse blew, your abuse of the GPIO probably caused the entire chip to latch up, drawing very high current and causing a silicon firestorm on a chip-wide scale as many thousands of transistors lost their lives in a matter of milliseconds.

It might have been possible to get this to work with a PNP transistor (by tying to the 3.3V supply since your motor supply is isolated) but I would strongly suggest using a logic-level n-channel MOSFET with some gate resistance in series, like 10K. The usual circuit looks like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcVlMq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 is to emphasize that the high motor current flows through the wire from the battery (-) terminal to the source of M1 and not through the RPi. The Schottky diode D1 is to absorb the inductive kick when the transistor turns off.

Note: The MOSFET part number I show is an SOT-23 type. There are few through-hole MOSFETs guaranteed to work well with 3.3V drive- you can use a breakout board if you find the part a bit small to work with directly.

Comment: Thanks for this, I definitely should have read more about where the voltages were heading on the PNP transistor. Did not expect the base would be at ~8.3V at all! Will be sure to pick up a MOSFET as well when I order a new chip :)

Answer (score 0):

A pnp transistor at 9V would be way above the 3.3V safe voltage of your Rpi. The lack of a resistor would make the problem worse by not limiting the current to the 16mA limit of the RPi main chip.

Typically you want a low side npn  driver for a RPi type board.

But this would not blow the fuse on a Rpi. Only a higher current would. Double check your circuit